# Roblox Studio - How to remove quotations around a string

Tags: lua, roblox

I was wondering if you guys can help me with something. I've been working on this for a long time and ran into a problem I can't resolve. I'm kind of a really bad debugger, in fact.

```
e = encode("print('test')")
wait()
d = decode(e)
print(d)
```

Encode and Decode is a function, think of it as a way to encrypt the string and decrypt. But I was seeing when you print(d) it prints out print('test') and I was wondering if there is a way to run "print('test') without printing it. So I was thinking if you guys can help me remove the quotations " " right after d = decode(e) to make it a callable function. For example:

```
d = decode(e)
d() -- this would print "test" in the output, much like loadstring
```

I also did some research about gsub but I have no knowledge about it because I haven't seen it been used many times. If you guys can help me, it would be 500x more appreciative than you would think. This would help me so much! If you need extra information, please reply and i'll reply to immediately.

Comment: Temporary redefine `print` function.

Comment: Isn't `load`/`loadstring` exactly what you're after (to evaluate `d` and execute the code it contains – printing only `test`)?

Comment: Its for an obfuscating process and if i use loadstring they can easily reverse with 

loadstring = print

at the beginning of the script
And yes, I already tried loadstring and thats what im trying to avoid

Also how would I redefine print?

Answer (score 1):

You can use _G global variable. It supports transfers from strings to functions. For example, you can build a type of encryption and make a string called `loadstring` then insert that variable into _G[variable] and it'll work fine.